# How to concatenate multiple columns vertically efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

for the end goal, I want to create a table that looks like something like this:

```
Table 1
option_ID person_ID option
1         1         B
2         1         
3         2         C
4         2         A
5         3         A
6         3         B
```

The idea is that a  person can choose up to 2 options out of 3 (in this case person 1 only chose 1 option). However, when my raw data format puts the 3 options into one single column, ie:

```
Table 2
person_ID option
1         B
2         C,A
3         A,B
```

What I usually do is the use 'Text to Columns' function using the ',' delimiter in Excel, and manually concatenate the 2 columns vertically. However, I find this method to become impractical when faced with more options (say 10 or even 20). Is there a way for me to get from  `Table 2` to `Table 1` efficiently using postgresql or some other methods?

Comment: I don't understand id = 2.

Comment: I don't understand which of those two tables represent the actual data in your database?

Answer (score 1):

use string_agg() function.

```
select person_ID, string_agg(option, ',') as option 
from table1
group by person_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_split_to_table()`:

```
select row_number() over () as id,
       t.person_id, v.option
from t cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(t.option, ',') option
order by person_id, option;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d56b4fde694e3dce9569e2c662de15be) is a db<>fiddle.

Actually, if you want the exactly two rows per personid:

```
select row_number() over () as id, t.person_id, v.option
from t cross join lateral
     (values (1, split_part(t.option, ',', 1)), (2, split_part(t.option, ',', 2))) v(pos, option)
order by person_id, pos;
```

Comment: thanks for this, however I am getting and error which says that column "options" does not exist